# contradiction in the definition of exponents of congruence class in modular arithmatics

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, definition

I know that if $a\equiv b\pmod n  $ ,then $a^k\equiv b^k\pmod n$ where $k \in Z^{\geq0}$.However , i saw a general definition in Discrete mathematics and applications by Sussanna 's book. It says that there is not any restriction for $k$ ,i.e , $k$ can be any integer such as the negatives , but i hesitated about this definiton. So , i want to ask you that what is the correct definiton for exponents which are in congruence class modulo. Is $k \in Z^{\geq0}$ or $k \in Z$ ?

Comment: The issue is that $a^{-1}$, say, might not even be defined.  You need $\gcd(a,n)=1$ for that.  If you have that, then any $k$ will work.

Comment: The book is sloppy. at least in that particular instance. The theorem is stated without proof, and you're right, it sounds as though it would be claimed for all integers. On the other hand, the proof is left as an exercise, and the problem statement in that exercise clearly asks the reader to prove (by induction) for $k \geqslant 1$. You'd better trust lulu on this one.